# Eagle CAD Limiting My Board Size

Tags: eaglecad

I had been using Visio to create my schematics for years but am now launching a product for which I will need PCBs manufactured.  I hate having to learn a (for me) completely new software program, but I digress.

I downloaded the free version of Eagle.  Played with it for an hour or two and decided this wouldn't be too bad to pick up.  Since the larges board I plan on producing will be 7.5" x 2.75" (which calculates to about 133 Sq CM), I bought a 3 year subscription of the Pro version, which states that it supports producing boards up to 160 Sq CM.  So far so good.  Then I spent a couple days creating the schematic as I learned the program.  All is well at this point.

The frustration came when I found that even with the MARK adjustments I could not place parts on a board 7" long even if it was only 1" wide.  I went back and looked at the Autodesk website again and it says nothing about maximum dimensions, only a maximum board size of 160 Sq CM.  I spent quite awhile messing with it before I came looking for answers.

Does anyone have any workarounds, or am I just stuck?

---

Sorry, the versions available for a fee are "Standard" and "Premium", not Pro.  I bought the Standard version for the reasons stated in my original post.  On their site where you buy the subscription the option listed for Standard only states 160 Sq CM as the maximum board size, with no reference to specific dimension restrictions.

After buying it and then realizing the unstated restriction I went ahead and bought the Premium edition too, so I could continue working to complete the project.  That did take care of the issue in a very expensive manner.  I am hoping they will reverse the charges for the initial Standard edition purchase.

Had I not already invested such a large amount of time in working on this with Eagle, I would have looked for other options.  The jump from $300 for a 3 year subscription to $500 for a 1 year subscription is a pretty steep jump to get what I needed to make it work, and in my view to address something that was falsely advertised.

Oh well, here I am.  Sorry for my whining.  I appreciate the responses.

Comment: Traditionally Eagle has supported up to the Eurocard size of 160*100mm.  It looks like neither dimension can be more than that.  So the description of 160sqcm is not really correct. The version I purchased that version many years ago has this limitation..

Comment: There is no "Pro". What is the actual name and version number of the software you bought?

Comment: If you have purchased this product, I would imagine you are entitled to customer support, they would be your first (and maybe only) people to contact to resolve this issue.